# AngularJS and Bootstrap tab behavior not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So here is my code for my view:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="my-pill">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab0" data-toggle="tab">Tools
                        Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Fair Trade Judge</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Awards</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Draft Buddy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Add A League</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Insult Generator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">League Poll</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab7" data-toggle="tab">Smart Rankings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab8" data-toggle="tab">Composite Rankings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">Waiver Wire Pickup
                        Aid</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab0">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h2>Tool Descriptions</h2>
                            <h3>Fair Trade Judge</h3>
                            <p>This tool will help you decide whether or not a proposed
                                trade is fair</p>
                            <h3>Awards</h3>
                            <p>Weekly awards given out to teams who have the best, and
                                worst weeks in the league</p>
                            <h3>Draft Buddy</h3>
                            <p>Use this tool to aid you during your big draft day</p>
                            <h3>Add A League</h3>
                            <p>This isn't really a tool, and doesn't fit on the
                                dashboard</p>
                            <h3>Insult Generator</h3>
                            <p>Let our team analysis algorithm pick apart any team in
                                your league with relevant insults</p>
                            <h3>League Poll</h3>
                            <p>Rank every team in your league on a weekly basis. Overall
                                rankings will be calculated based on the poll</p>
                            <h3>Smart Rankings</h3>
                            <p>This tool ranks every team in your league based on
                                complex rankings algorithm, that factors in more than just your
                                W-L-T record</p>
                            <h3>Composite Rankings</h3>
                            <p>Ever wonder what your record would be if you played every
                                team every week instead of the head to head match-up style?
                                This tool will tell you what your overall record would be</p>
                            <h3>Waiver Wire Pickup Aid</h3>
                            <p>See who our analysis of your team determines you should
                                pick up off of the waiver wire this week</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1" >
                    <h2>Select the teams that are going to do a trade, then
                        select the players</h2>
                    <div ng-controller="FTJController" class="teamWrapper">
                        <div class="col-md-6 team" style="float: left;">
                            {{list1}} <select ng-model="selectedTeam1"
                                ng-options="item as item.teamName for item in teams track by item.teamID"
                                ng-change="getRoster1(selectedTeam1)">
                                <option value="">Team 1</option>
                            </select>
                            <table class="table-striped" style="width: 100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Name</td>
                                    <td>Position</td>
                                    <td>NFLTeamName</td>
                                    <td>InjuryCode</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-repeat="player1 in roster1">
                                    <td><input type="radio" ng-value="{{player1.PlayerID}}"
                                        ng-model="selected1" ng-change="addID1(selected1)"
                                        name="selected1" /></td>
                                    <td>{{player1.Name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{player1.Position}}</td>
                                    <td>{{player1.NFLTeamName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{player1.InjuryCode}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-offset-6 team">
                            {{list2}} <select ng-model="selectedTeam2"
                                ng-options="item as item.teamName for item in teams track by item.teamID"
                                ng-change="getRoster2(selectedTeam2)">
                                <option value="">Team 2</option>
                            </select>
                            <table class="table-striped" style="width: 100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Name</td>
                                    <td>Position</td>
                                    <td>NFLTeamName</td>
                                    <td>InjuryCode</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-repeat="player2 in roster2">
                                    <td><input type="radio" ng-value="{{player2.PlayerID}}"
                                        ng-model="selected2" ng-change="addID2(selected2)"
                                        name="selected2" /></td>
                                    <td>{{player2.Name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{player2.Position}}</td>
                                    <td>{{player2.NFLTeamName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{player2.InjuryCode}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="button">
                            <input type="button" value="compare players"
                                ng-click="comparePlayers()" />
                            <div>Is this trade fair? {{FTJ}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Whenever I try to click on one of the tabs, instead of loading the data, it will redirect me to my login page. I don't want any redirection, since all the data I need loaded after login. If I change the class of tab1 to active, I get the data behavior I want, so I think it's an issue with Bootstrap. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is my controller file (the calls to API are working fine)

```
HomeController.$inject = ['UserService', '$rootScope'];
function HomeController(UserService, $rootScope) {
var vm = this;

vm.user = null;
vm.allUsers = [];
vm.deleteUser = deleteUser;

initController();

function initController() {
    loadCurrentUser();

}

function loadCurrentUser() {
    UserService.GetByEmail($rootScope.globals.currentUser.email)
        .then(function (user) {
            vm.user = user.data;
        });
}

function deleteUser(id) {
    UserService.Delete(id)
    .then(function () {
        loadAllUsers();
    });
}
}

FTJController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
function FTJController($scope, $http) {
$scope.list1 = 'Select Team 1';
$scope.list2 = 'Select Team 2';
//$scope.selectedTeam = null;
$scope.teams = [];
$scope.players1 = [];
$scope.players2 = [];
$scope.roster1 = null;
$scope.roster2 = null;
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: './rest/LeagueTeams?LeagueID=1682132'
}).success(function (result) {
    $scope.teams = result;
});
console.log("in controller");
$scope.getRoster1 = function(selectedTeam){
    console.log("in getRoster with teamID = " + selectedTeam.teamID);
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: './rest/Roster?LeagueID=1682132&TeamID=' +selectedTeam.teamID + '&Week=1&Year=2015'
    }).then(function (result){
        $scope.roster1 = result.data;
    });

}
//duplicating for now, should change to use the same method for both rosters
$scope.getRoster2 = function(selectedTeam){
    console.log("in getRoster with teamID = " + selectedTeam.teamID);
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: './rest/Roster?LeagueID=1682132&TeamID=' +selectedTeam.teamID + '&Week=1&Year=2015'
    }).then(function (result){
        $scope.roster2 = result.data;
    });
}

$scope.comparePlayers = function(){
    console.log("testingsss");
    console.log($scope.players1);
    console.log($scope.players2);
    console.log('call: ./rest/FTJ?PlayerID1=' + $scope.players1 + '&PlayerID2=' + $scope.players1);
    console.log('Is $scope.players1 ' + ($scope.players1) + ' > $scope.players2 ' + $scope.players1 + ' ?');
    console.log('comparison');
    console.log($scope.players1 > $scope.players2);
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: './rest/FTJ?PlayerID1=' + $scope.players1 + '&PlayerID2=' + $scope.players2
    }).then(function (result){
        console.log('result.data');
        console.log(result.data);
        if (result.data){
            $scope.FTJ = "Hell yea";
        } else {
            $scope.FTJ = "f no";
        }
    });
};
$scope.addID1 = function(s){
    $scope.players1 = s;
    console.log($scope.players1);

};
$scope.addID2 = function(s){
    $scope.players2 = s;
    console.log($scope.players2);
};
}
```

And here is my app.js file with the routing:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
    .config(config)
    .run(run);

config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html/',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'login/login.view.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

        .when('/register', {
            controller: 'RegisterController',
            templateUrl: 'register/register.view.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}

run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http'];
function run($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
    // keep user logged in after page refresh
    $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
    if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' +     $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
    }

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
        var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
        var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
        if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    });
}
})();
```

How do I fix the routing so that when I click on tab1, it will just show the data and move to that tab instead of redirecting to login? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It happens because of angular routing...
You can just add to every anchor tag the following attribute
*target="_self"*

For example: `<li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" target="_self">Fair Trade Judge</a></li>`

Hope it resolves it.

Comment: i have used above but everytime page reload i dont need this i have change only tabs

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-target="#tab1"` instead of `href="#tab1"`

Answer (score 0):

Angular router is routing to #tab1 when you click on the link. Since there is no such route defined and login screen is the default route, it must be displaying the login screen.

you could use [angular-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to get bootstrap work easily with angular.

Comment: Hey, could you take a look at the code now? I added the js files, can you help me setup the routes correctly, I am still not sure.

Comment: it's nothing wrong with routes, but the issue is when you click on tabs, angular thinks it's routing to #tab1 (example) route. Since there is no such route it ends up going to default route which is login. So use angular-ui since it's the angular way of using bootstrap scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Your default page because there is no defined route to be found.

So, what you can do is you can handle tab click event and prevent this default behaviour using

```
e.preventDefault();
```

you have two options:

1. add `ng-click="show($event)"` for each tab

   For example, in controller

   ```
   $scope.show = function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       jQuery('.nav-pills[href="e.targrt.hash"]').tab('show')
   };
   ```

   Check Bootstrap document for more detail: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs
2. or add directive to handle event.

   ```
   <a show-tab href="#tab0" data-toggle="tab">Tools Home</a>

   app.directive('showTab', function () {

   // here first prevent deault behaviour of a tab,  then add new click event which invokes jQuery related stuff for tabs
   return function (scope, iElement, iAttributes) {        
       iElement.click(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $(iElement).tab('show');
       });
   };
   ```

   This is the better option.

Please check this link how to do it: https://www.grobmeier.de/bootstrap-tabs-with-angular-js-25112012.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this adding to your angjularjs

```
    $(".yourTabClassName anchorTag").click(function(anyName) {
        anyName.preventDefault();
    });
```

Ex:

```
    $(".nav a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

buddy, I think you are missing role='tab' attribute which does not invoke the angular router

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing this. You'll notice that i'm using `<app-tab-profile></app-tab-profile>` in the Profile tab-pane. I'm not sure if this is best practice, but it seems to work. Routing is NOT setup for the TabProfileComponent.

```
<div class="section-container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab"><app-tab-profile></app-tab-profile></div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('ul.tabs').tabs();
}, 100);
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).